# Selecting all values from multivalued field in Oracle c11 - SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, cross-apply, multivalue-database

I am trying to select all the values from multivalued data column. Values are separated with ý.

This query I wrote does exactly what I intended, but unfortunately I am working on 11g so I can't use `CROSS APPLY`. Any suggestions how to go around `CROSS APPLY`? Or any other ideas?

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR (MFIELD, '([^ý]+)',1,l.lvl,NULL) AS item
FROM TABLE
CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT LEVEL AS lvl
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( MFIELD, 'ý' ) 
)l;
```

Comment: What is "Oracle c11"? There's no such version. Did you mean Oracle 11g?

Comment: @Littlefoot yep sry should be 11g

Answer (score 0):

Switch to

```
SQL> WITH
  2     my_table (mfield)
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT 'abcýdef' FROM DUAL
  5         UNION ALL
  6         SELECT 'xyzýmnoýzzz' FROM DUAL
  7         UNION ALL
  8         SELECT 'ý18524ý2879' FROM DUAL)
  9  SELECT mfield,
 10         REGEXP_SUBSTR (mfield,
 11                        '[^ý]+',
 12                        1,
 13                        COLUMN_VALUE) AS item
 14    FROM my_table
 15         CROSS JOIN
 16         TABLE (
 17            CAST (
 18               MULTISET (
 19                      SELECT LEVEL
 20                        FROM DUAL
 21                  CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
 22                             REGEXP_COUNT (LTRIM (mfield, 'ý'), 'ý') + 1)
 23                  AS SYS.odcinumberlist));

MFIELD      ITEM
----------- -----------
abcýdef     abc
abcýdef     def
xyzýmnoýzzz xyz
xyzýmnoýzzz mno
xyzýmnoýzzz zzz
ý18524ý2879 18524
ý18524ý2879 2879

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Am getting an error
```
ORA-01788: CONNECT BY clause required in this query block
01788. 00000 -  "CONNECT BY clause required in this query block"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 6 Column: 8
```
Any idea why?

Comment: Ah, yes - sorry, didn't pay attention to regular expressions. Should've been `column_value`. Have a look at edited code (which now contains test case as well).

Comment: Thanks so much.
I noticed that it sometimes return null though.
e.g.
ý18524ý2879 |  18524 ;
ý18524ý2879 |  2879   ;
ý18524ý2879 |  (null)   ;

Comment: That's because of delimiter at the beginning of the string. Modify REGEXP_COUNT to `REGEXP_COUNT (LTRIM (mfield, 'ý'), 'ý') + 1)`

Comment: You are absolutely wonderful.
Thank you so much. 
Am wrinkling my brain for hours on this one.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad if it helped.